# Nagios /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Tags: linux, nagios

when I'm running the following command:

```
[root@ssbpops01 libexec]# /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

i got the next error:

```
Nagios Core 4.0.4
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 03-14-2014
License: GPL

Website: http://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
   Read main config file okay...
**Error: Could not open config directory '/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers' for reading.
   Error processing object config files!**
***> One or more problems was encountered while processing the config files...

     **Check your configuration file(s) to ensure that they contain valid
     directives and data defintions.  If you are upgrading from a previous
     version of Nagios, you should be aware that some variables/definitions
     may have been removed or modified in this version.  Make sure to read
     the HTML documentation regarding the config files, as well as the
     'Whats New' section to find out what has changed.**
```

can you please assist?

Answer (score 2):

**/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers** does not exist. Create directory or find the line in your **/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg**:

```
cfg_dir=/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers
```

And comment it:

```
#cfg_dir=/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers
```

Comment: It fixed my problem. Thanks for sharing.